Unreachable statement when upgrading APEX class version
I am trying to upgrade an APEX class version from 27 to 58 and I am getting an error saying 'Unreachable statement' while trying to save it.
Apex method:
    public PageReference save() {
            if (!String.isBlank(selectedExpectImp)) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'To bulk update in Expected Impact, please click on the Bulk Update button'));
            }
            try {
                if (!maintImp.isEmpty() && maintImp != null){
                    update maintImp;
                }
                else {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'No impact is associated to this case. Please click on the Cancel button'));
                }
            } catch(DMlException ex) {
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,ex.getMessage()));
            }
        
            return ApexPages.currentPage();
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + contextId);  //Error at this line
            return pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            
        }

Screenshot:

I have no idea on how else this needs to be handled. Can anyone please suggest.

You have an unconditional return, so any lines after that are unreachable. The older compiler didn't give this error, but the newer compiler does.
// Unconditional return means any lines following are unreachable.
return ApexPages.currentPage();
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + contextId);  //Error at this line
return pageRef.setRedirect(true);

The solution is to remove the first return statement:
// Unconditional return means any lines following are unreachable.
// return ApexPages.currentPage();
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + contextId);  // Fixed!
return pageRef.setRedirect(true);


I would say that if they want to preserve the previous behavior, it would be rather suitable to comment any line after the first return statement.

@MariiaIllarionova It's possible, but I think the redirect was intentional, perhaps to refresh the view state of the Visualforce page, for example, so I opted for the later return. Of course, this might introduce a bug, but it might also fix a bug! All we know from the code is that only one return is needed.

Since API version 42.0, dead code is flagged during compilation itself.
Source.
As per attached screenshot, method will always return at line #89. So any lines after it will never execute, ever! Hence line #90, and #91 are nothing but dead code.
To fix this, re-write this method to eliminate any dead code, while keeping its business logic intact.
And while you're at it, why not upgrade all the way to API version 61.0? It's better to always upgrade to the latest API version, unless you need some behavior only available in some previous version.
